# Python Pandas: Keeping only dataframe rows containing first occurrence of an item

Tags: python, pandas

I have this:

```
    Date value
0   1975     a
21  1975     b
1   1976     b
22  1976     c
3   1977     a
2   1977     b
4   1978     c
25  1978     d
5   1979     e
26  1979     f
6   1980     a
27  1980     f
```

I am having trouble finding a way to keep only the lines containing the first occurrence of a 'value'. I want to drop duplicate 'values', keeping the row with the lowest 'Date'.The end result should be:

```
    Date value
0   1975     a
21  1975     b
22  1976     c
25  1978     d
5   1979     e
26  1979     f
```

Answer (score 16):

To make a bit more explicit what Quazi posted: `drop_duplicates()` is what you need. By default, it *keeps* the first occurence and drops everything thereafter - look at [the manual](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for more information. So, to be sure, you should do

```
>>> dataframe = oldDf.sort('Date').drop_duplicates(subset=['value'])
>>> dataframe
Out[490]: 
    Date value
0   1975     a
21  1975     b
22  1976     c
25  1978     d
5   1979     e
26  1979     f
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, if substituting subset for cols as Quazi posted

Comment: Oh right, if you're at `0.13`, `subset` will not work yet. Complications all over the place :)

Comment: nowadays, you need `sort_values` instead of `sort`

Answer (score 6):

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['value'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: `cols` is deprecated.

Comment: I used the same manual page you linked, which is showing cols. Can you tell which one should I use here then?

Comment: Well, the manual is from `0.13`. I run `0.14` and got `FutureWarning: cols is deprecated, use subset instead warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning)`. It's not a big deal, I just thought I put an "fyi" here, since these posts stay for "eternity" :)

Comment: Also adjusted my link. Apparently, `dev` in the link relates to `0.13`, while `stable` is the `0.14` manual.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes I'm using 0.13 also, so got no warning. Thanks. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3):

FooBar is right, but sort is deprecated and replaced by sort_values

```
dataframe = oldDf.sort_values('Date').drop_duplicates(subset=['value'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easier method is to use groupby

```
df = oldDf.groupby('value').first().reset_index()
```